# FSharp site on shared server, which dll's do I need to include in the bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, f#

Which dll's do I need to include in the bin folder?
or do I need to install F# on the server it self ?

N.B: 
**Resolved**

- All the FSharp dlls are now in the site Bin
- The site is deployed using the Publish option from Visual Studio

  - The **allow precompiled site to be updatable** has to be **unchecked**

Error from my site:

**The system cannot find the file specified**

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

**Source Error**:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace**:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +2097
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +140
   Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.Internal.Compiler.compileFiles(String args, CompilerResults res) +120
   Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.Internal.Compiler.compileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames, CompilerResults results, FastFunc`2 sortf) +278
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +23
   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +843
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +164
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +267
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +582
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +93
   System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetReferencedType(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean allowNoCompile) +325
   System.Web.UI.PageParser.EnsureMasterPageFileFromConfigApplied() +89
   System.Web.UI.PageParser.HandlePostParse() +16
   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() +155
   System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +105
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +54
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +182
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +29
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +267
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +582
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +93
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +54
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +139
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +128
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +161
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you 'pre-compile' the web site using the aspnet_compiler.exe tool (or using the Publish button in Visual Studio) without compiling it as "updatable" (meaning that all ASPX and FS files have to be compiled into DLLs) then I think you'll need just:

- FSharp.Core.dll (contains the core F# libraries, lists, tuples, etc.)
- possibly FSharp.PowerPack.dll (as Robert mentioned)

Other DLLs from the F# installation shouldn't be needed for the runtime. If you want to compile the Web application on the server (using the F# CodeDOM) (i.e. deploy it as an updatable web site), then you'll need to install F# on the server and you'll need the rights to spawn "fsc.exe" (so that doesn't look like a case for shared server).

Answer (score 1):

Installing F# on the server will definitely cure your problems, but isn't strictly necessary. You will have definitely picked up a dependency on FSharp.core.dll, you may also have picked up a dependency on FSharp.PowerPack.dll if you have referenced it from your project, and well any other FSharp.*.dlls that you may have referenced. You can generally use reflector to find which dlls your application depends on.

Comment: I have reference the two dlls which i reference and still get weird errors, I may have to copy the whole lot into my bin directory.. then remove the ones that i do not need?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by unchecking the allow this precompiled site to be updatable and by having all the dlls in the directory.

Thanks for the suggestions.